# Does IntelliJ have feature for adding (or removing) 'this.' prefix in front of appropriate points in the code shown in code editor?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-editor

Some people like to omit the `this.` prefix to calls, such as:

```
addColor( Color.PURPLE ) ;
```

… while other folks prefer to include explicitly the `this.` prefix, such as:

```
this.addColor( Color.PURPLE ) ;
```

Does IntelliJ offer any feature for automatically adding and/or removing the `this.` prefix within the code shown in the editor?

Answer (score 2):

## *Save Actions* plugin

The plugin, [*Save Actions*](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions), offers this functionality.

When installed (and activated) you can find these options under <kbd>Other Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Save Actions</kbd>:

- Add this to field access
- Add this to method access
- Remove unnecessary this to field and method

*The plugin can be configured to execute these actions on save / idling / window deactivation.*

## Built into IntelliJ

**InteliJ IDEA** itself offers these checkstyle functionalities:

<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + S</kbd> -> <kbd>Editor</kbd> -> <kbd>Inspections</kbd> -> <kbd>Code style issues</kbd>:

- Unnecessary 'this' qualifier
- Instance field access not qualified with 'this'
- Instance method call not qualified with 'this'

To inspect the code and apply the fix:
<kbd>Code</kbd> -> <kbd>Inspect</kbd>

To auto apply fixes:
<kbd>Code</kbd> -> <kbd>Cleanup</kbd>

Comment: Unfortunately, version 2.2.0 of *Save Actions* plugin crashes with the launch of IntelliJ version 2021.3 EAP. This plugin would seem to be a good solution, once the crashing is sorted in future versions.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ has the following inspections to add a `this` qualifier to method calls and field references:

```
Java | Code style issues | Instance field access not qualified with 'this'
Java | Code style issues | Instance method call not qualified with 'this'
```

And the following inspection to remove unnecessary `this` qualifiers:

```
Java | Code style issues | Unnecessary 'this' qualifier
```

All three inspections have a quick fix, and code can be fixed in batch using `Code | Inspect Code` and applying the fix on the result or `Code | Cleanup` to immediately clean up the code.

The Save Actions plugin just calls these built-in inspections.

Comment: Cool, I hope you don't mind I updated my answer, I figured IntelliJ had to offer these checkstyles but I didn't see them last night.